# java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using java api for  kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1 installed in  ubuntu box and getting **java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer** when I run High Level Consumer. It works fine with kafka-console-consumer.sh  command but not with java api

Comment: its hard to say whats going on at your end by looking at one line of exception. could you please post your high level consumer code

Comment: i am using same example available https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example . It works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't

Comment: we need more info here, posts some more logs ..have you tried something out ? it helps people to understand the problem better

Comment: My server log https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B56TlBnM-Q5VQmJramJTY0tzUHc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: and its running on localhost with one partition